# What to do when an answer is just a (very good) request for information?

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practice, answers

What should I do when I come upon a question that's missing some information, which has been requested...but only in an answer that does not actually attempt to *answer* the question, nor even to outline or even hint at how the information could lead to an answer? Should I repost it in summary (and in quotes or my own words) as a comment, in case it's deleted? Should I flag it for moderator attention? Should I do both? Neither? Something else?

[This "answer"](https://askubuntu.com/a/10868/22949) is what I have in mind (though who knows if it will still be there, and still fit this description, when you are reading this). But I find this happens frequently, and I've never been quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These should be flagged as **not an answer**:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It
>   should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted
>   altogether.

When you do so, you should probably also post a comment explaining that the answer's content needs to be moved into a comment on the question (since it is clearly asking for clarification from the OP), and possibly add a link to the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) if the answerer's reputation score seems low enough to justify it.

Comment: Yes! Posting a comment on the question is *such* a great help for us dealing with the flags.

Comment: There's also a script for [pro-forma comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).